# How to compute derivative in Maxima?

Tags: maxima

I want to calculate the seventh derivative of tan(x) at x=pi/4 in Maxima:

```
f(x) := diff(tan(x), x, 7);
f(%pi / 4);
```

Yet I cannot get the result. Ay ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like this,

```
at(diff(tan(x),x,7),[x=%pi/4]);
```

The function `diff` returns a function as its result. You can evaluate this function at a point by using the `at` function.

Another way of doing is like so,

```
f: diff(tan(x), x, 7);
at(f, [x=%pi/4]);
```

Now `f` is just a variable that holds the output of `diff` and then `at` is used to evaluate it at a point.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

When you define a function via `:=`, the function body is quoted (i.e., not evaluated). You can tell Maxima to evaluate an expression by using the quote-quote `''` operator.

```
(%i1) display2d : false $
(%i2) f(x) := ''(diff (tan(x), x, 7));
(%o2) f(x):=64*sec(x)^2*tan(x)^6+1824*sec(x)^4*tan(x)^4+2880*sec(x)^6*tan(x)^2
        +272*sec(x)^8
(%i3) f(%pi / 4);
(%o3) 34816
```

Note that `''` has the possibly-surprising property that it is only applied once, when an expression is entered, not every time the expression is evaluated.

Comment: Why is `display2d : false` necessary?

Comment: @Oswald It's not necessary, it just makes the output easier to read here.